# I am trying to create an Infocenter. I want to add conditions in helpData.xml in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[3 colors show contents from 3 different jar files[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6HMq.jpg)I am  trying to create an Infocenter using Eclipse Help. I want to add  conditions in `helpData.xml` in Eclipse so that different TOC (only relevant JARs are visible) respective of the product selected (as a parameter).

I want to have display different `toc.xml` as per different product selected by the user.
When the user selects a product from the home page, the if statement displays the TOC and hide others as defined in the if/else statement of `helpData.xml`.

My `helpData.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rule>
    <if>
        <conditions>
            <condition var="ABC" operator="&gt;">400</condition>
            <!-- more conditions possible -->
        </conditions>
        <statements>
            <extensions>
                <tocOrder>
                    <toc id="/8206_1912_000/toc.xml"/>
                    <toc id="/access_guide/toc.xml"/>
                    <toc id="/transaction_guide/toc.xml"/>       
                </tocOrder>
                <hidden>
                    <toc id="/information_center/toc.xml"/>
                    <toc id="/ic_custom/toc.xml"/>
                </hidden>
            </extensions>       
        </statements>
    </if>
    <elseif>
        <conditions></conditions>
        <statements>
            <extensions>
                <tocOrder>
                    <toc id="/8206_1912_000/toc.xml"/>
                    <toc id="/transaction_guide/toc.xml"/>    
                    <toc id="/access_guide/toc.xml"/>   
                </tocOrder>
                <hidden>
                    <toc id="/information_center/toc.xml"/>
                    <toc id="/ic_custom/toc.xml"/>
                </hidden>
            </extensions>
        </statements>
    </elseif>
    <else>
        <statements>
            <extensions>
                <tocOrder>
                    <toc id="/access_guide/toc.xml"/>
                    <toc id="/transaction_guide/toc.xml"/>
                    <toc id="/8206_1912_000/toc.xml"/>       
                </tocOrder>
                <hidden>
                    <toc id="/information_center/toc.xml"/>
                    <toc id="/ic_custom/toc.xml"/>
                </hidden>
            </extensions>
        </statements>
    </else>
</rule>
```

Comment: The [Help data XML format](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_setup_help_data.htm) does not support `<rule>`, `<if>`, `<conditions>`, etc. In contrast to the `helpData.xml`, you can use [filters in the TOC file](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_dynamic_filters.htm).

Comment: there are a bunch of jar files for every product  with every jar file having its own toc.I am trying to have a single help center for multiple products,with users able to see the information of the product selected by them.(Similar to  learn.microsoft.com)

Comment: If you want the search scope to be per product, I recommend running different Eclipse instances in parallel (with maybe only one Infocenter base installation).